# Excel VBA Runtime Error '13' Type Mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime, mismatch

I am having problems with the definition of my variables I think but I cannot see where or why. It's quite a simple code to count the amount of lessons teachers have allocated. The information is in the worksheet 'Subects and Teachers 2018' and has to be printed in the worksheet 'Teachers'. The quantities always appear on the left of the name.

Here's the code. If anyone could give me a hint on what I'm defining incorrectly I would be very thankful! Debugging suggests that the problem is in the line which has ***** at the end (not part of the code).

```
Sub Counter2018()
    Dim Var1 As String
    Dim CVar1 As Integer

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    For k = 2 To 50
        Var1 = Worksheets("Teachers").Cells(k, 3)
        CVar1 = 0
        For i = 2 To 45
            For j = 2 To 45
                If Worksheets("2018 Subjects and Teachers").Cells(i, j) = Var1 Then
                    CVar1 = CVar1 + Worksheets("2018 Subjects and Teachers").Cells(i, j - 1) *****
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        Worksheets("Teachers").Cells(k, 5) = CVar1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of i & j when it crashes and what is the data in the cell i, j-1?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to check this. I'm quite new to all this.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you find out about the immediate window - you can step though your code by pressing F8 and use this `?i` and `?j` to find out what the values are at that point in the code :)  Good luck & have fun

Answer (score 0):

Try this version (untested)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Counter2018()
    Dim wsTeachers As Worksheet, wsSubjects As Worksheet

    Set wsTeachers = Worksheets("Teachers")
    Set wsSubjects = Worksheets("2018 Subjects and Teachers")

    Dim teacher As String, counter As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    For k = 2 To 50
        teacher = wsTeachers.Cells(k, 3)
        counter = 0
        For i = 2 To 45
            For j = 2 To 45
                If wsSubjects.Cells(i, j).Value2 = teacher Then
                    If Not IsError(wsSubjects.Cells(i, j - 1)) Then
                        counter = counter + Val(wsSubjects.Cells(i, j - 1).Value2)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        wsTeachers.Cells(k, 5) = counter
    Next
End Sub
```

---

I think the Type Mismatch error is caused by some of the cells in `wsSubjects.Cells(i, j - 1)`

That counter expects numbers in that column, but there might be some strings or errors in there

Comment: I recommend to always use `Long` instead of `Integer` especially when iterating cells. (eg. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle). And there is no advantage in using `Integer` at all (only disadvantages). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613

Comment: Thank you very much Paul Bica! It didn't work at first as the line 'teacher = wsTeachers.Cells(k, 3)' was before k was defined and so it started at a cell in row 0. Once i put this inside the loop it worked perfectly. Many thanks everyone!

Comment: @Peh - good point; I never use Integers, but this was an oversight which is now fixed

Comment: @SantiagoMariaBorioPeñaloza - I made 2 edits including the line `teacher = wsTeachers.Cells(k, 3` Inside the k loop